# Null point exception when trying to add a List<String> to HashMap

Tags: android, hashmap

I'm trying to add list of string to HashMap, I have shown below the way I'm trying to do. But I'm getting null point exception (I have commented in the code where I'm getting the exception). 
Can anyone spot what is the mistake I'm making.

```
     private List<Product> mCartList;
     List<String> listDataHeader;
     HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

        List<String> listdescription = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> listcrust = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> listsize = new ArrayList<String>();
        String descriptionString;
        String crustString;
        String sizeString;

        for (int i = 0; i < mCartList.size(); i++) {

            mCartList.get(i).selected = false;
            hot_number = mCartList.size();


            if (mCartList.get(i).description != null
                    && !mCartList.get(i).description.isEmpty()) {
                descriptionString = mCartList.get(i).description;

                listdescription.add(descriptionString);
                System.out.println("listdescription = " + listdescription);
            }

            if (mCartList.get(i).crust != null
                    && !mCartList.get(i).crust.isEmpty()) {
                crustString = mCartList.get(i).crust;

                listcrust.add(crustString);
                System.out.println("listcrust = " + listcrust);
            }

            if (mCartList.get(i).size != null
                    && !mCartList.get(i).size.isEmpty()) {
                sizeString = mCartList.get(i).size;

                listsize.add(sizeString);
                System.out.println("listsize = " + listsize);
            }

        }

        listDataChild.put("listcrust", listcrust); // error occurs here
        listDataChild.put("listsize", listsize);

        listDataHeader.addAll(listdescription);

        System.out.println("listDataChild = " + listDataChild);
        System.out.println("listDataHeader = " + listDataHeader);
```

I have debugged and got the value for `listsize` in 88 line, but when I pass the line 93 the it gives the below mentioned exception.

[image]

Exception screen shot

[image]

Comment: you need to initialize that. HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild=new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't assigned object to the listDataChild member.

It looks at these are defined on class level:

```
 private List<Product> mCartList;
 List<String> listDataHeader;
 HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
```

And reset of the code is inside a method. Is this right?

By default the member is not initialized and set to null. In case you are trying to perform an operation on a null reference, it fails with the NullPointerException.

Try the following:

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Comment: Of course this fixes the NullPointerException but there is no background-information! See [this good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for more insight...

Comment: thanks for the answers, it really worked. I got new problem I have commented that. it will be great if u could take a look at it.

Comment: `List<String> listDataHeader;` is also uninitialized thus `.addAll(..)` in line #96 results in NullPointerException.

Answer (score 3):

Your *HashMap* (listDataChild) is not initialized on line 3.

Initialize it before putting values to it. If you don't initialize it, it will be *NULL* when you call the method *put* on it and all operations on *NULL* will give you a *NullPointerException*.

For example you could add initialization before calling the *put* method:

```
listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Comment: Good explanation, I don't know to whome I should vote because I got correct answer before yours

Answer (score 1):

I don't see, that you instantiate the listDataChild object, this will cause this, object is null at the point you want to add a new item.

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Comment: thanks for the answers, it really worked. I got the answer 1 early answer than yours. I got new problem I have commented that. it will be great if u could take a look at it.